# WPF DataGrid with Interaction.Triggers "CellEditEnding"

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to save my ViewModel row from a DataGrid (SelectionUnit="Cell") when a DataGridTextColumn is changed. Apparently DataGridTextColumn does not have any events, but i can hook up the DataGrid CellEditEnding event.

How do i reference the DataGridRow or the viewmodel that was changed in the CommandParameter?

```
<DataGrid>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SpreadSettingsChanged}" 
            CommandParameter="?" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```